# map vs mapValues in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm currently learning Spark and developing custom machine learning algorithms. My question is what is the difference between `.map()` and `.mapValues()` and what are cases where I clearly have to use one instead of the other?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`mapValues` is only applicable for PairRDDs, meaning RDDs of the form `RDD[(A, B)]`. In that case, `mapValues` operates on the *value* only (the second part of the tuple), while `map` operates on the *entire record* (tuple of key and value).

In other words, given `f: B => C` and `rdd: RDD[(A, B)]`, these two are identical (almost - see comment at the bottom):

```
val result: RDD[(A, C)] = rdd.map { case (k, v) => (k, f(v)) }

val result: RDD[(A, C)] = rdd.mapValues(f)
```

The latter is simply shorter and clearer, so when you just want to transform the values and keep the keys as-is, it's recommended to use `mapValues`.

On the other hand, if you want to transform the keys too (e.g. you want to apply `f: (A, B) => C`), you simply can't use `mapValues` because it would only pass the values to your function.

The last difference concerns **partitioning**: if you applied any custom partitioning to your RDD (e.g. using `partitionBy`), using `map` would "forget" that paritioner (the result will revert to default partitioning) as the keys might have changed; `mapValues`, however, preserves any partitioner set on the RDD.

Comment: I wonder if they play a role in performance, since I am trying to optimize [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39235576/unbalanced-factor-of-kmeans), but from what you said, I guess it won't make any difference...

Comment: @gsamaras it can have an impact in performance, as losing the partitioning information will force a shuffle down the road if you need to repartition again with the same key.

Answer (score 5):

When we use map() with a Pair RDD, we get access to both Key & value. few times we are only interested in accessing the value(& not key). In those case, we can use mapValues() instead of map().

**Example of mapValues**

```
val inputrdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("maths", 50), ("maths", 60), ("english", 65)))
val mapped = inputrdd.mapValues(mark => (mark, 1));

//
val reduced = mapped.reduceByKey((x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2))

reduced.collect
```

Array[(String, (Int, Int))] = Array((english,(65,1)), (maths,(110,2)))

```
val average = reduced.map { x =>
                           val temp = x._2
                           val total = temp._1
                           val count = temp._2
                           (x._1, total / count)
                           }

average.collect()
```

res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((english,65), (maths,55))

Answer (score 3):

`map` takes a function that transforms each element of a collection:

```
 map(f: T => U)
RDD[T] => RDD[U]
```

When `T` is a tuple we may want to only act on the values – not the keys
mapValues takes a function that maps the values in the inputs to the values in the output: `mapValues(f: V => W)`
Where `RDD[ (K, V) ] => RDD[ (K, W) ]`

#### Tip: use `mapValues` when you can avoid *reshuffle* when data is partitioned by key

Answer (score 3):

```
val inputrdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(("india", 250), ("england", 260), ("england", 180)))
```

(1)

```
map():-

val mapresult= inputrdd.map{b=> (b,1)}
mapresult.collect

Result-= Array(((india,250),1), ((england,260),1), ((english,180),1))
```

(2)

```
mapvalues():-

val mapValuesResult= inputrdd.mapValues(b => (b, 1));
mapValuesResult.collect
```

Result-

```
Array((india,(250,1)), (england,(260,1)), (england,(180,1)))
```

Comment: unless you are absolutely sure that you can fit all the data into memory, don't ever try to use `.collect`.