# Spark Mapvalues vs. Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I saw this question on stackoverflow asked by another user and I tried to write the code myself as I am trying to practice scala and spark:

The question was to find the per-key average from a list:

Assuming the list is: `( (1,1), (1,3), (2,4), (2,3), (3,1) )`

The code was:

```
val result = input.combineByKey(
(v) => (v, 1),
(acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)).
map{ case (key, value) => (key, value._1 / value._2.toFloat) }  
result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))
```

So basically the above code will create an RDD of type `[Int, (Int, Int)]` where the first `Int` is the key and the value is `(Int, Int)` where the first `Int` here is the addition of all the values with the same key and the second `Int` is the amount of times the key appeared.

**I understand what is going on but for some reason when I rewrite the code like this:**

```
val result = input.combineByKey(
(v) => (v, 1),
(acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)).
mapValues(value: (Int, Int) => (value._1 / value._2))
result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))
```

When I use mapValues instead of map with the `case` keyword the code doesn't work.It gives an error saying `error: not found: type /` What is the difference when using map with case and mapValues. Since I thought map values will just take the value (which in this case is a (Int,Int)) and return to you a new value and the key remains the same for the key value pair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [map vs mapValues in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696326/map-vs-mapvalues-in-spark)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
val result = input.combineByKey(
(v) => (v, 1),
(acc: (Int, Int), v) => (acc._1 + v, acc._2 + 1),
(acc1: (Int, Int), acc2: (Int, Int)) => (acc1._1 + acc2._1, acc1._2 + acc2._2)).
mapValues(value => (value._1 / value._2))
result.collectAsMap().map(println(_))
```

Comment: Oh this worked as well! Why is that you do not need the `value: (Int, Int)`? I also did this and it worked: `result.map(elem => (elem._1, (elem._2._1 / elem._2._2))).collectAsMap().map(println(_))`

Comment: @1290 I don't know the exact answer but you don't need to explicitly specify data type of rdd in spark transformations/actions.

Comment: Oh ok I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I found a good article to my problem: http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/12/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-4-pattern-matching-anonymous-functions.html

If anyone else has the same problem that explains it well!